# Where can I find palladium?

Tags: terraria

Seriously, why is it so hard to find this ore! I looked all the way down to hell across the map. I already destroyed a Demon Altar.

Comment: Make sure you've destroyed several altars, each one broken adds more ore to the world.

Comment: Are you sure your world doesn't have cobalt instead?

Answer (score 4):

If you can't find any on your map, smash some more altars.

Here is a chart:

- On a small map Palladium ore spawns below a depth of 760 feet (380 tiles).
- On a medium map Palladium ore spawns below a depth of 1,100 feet (550 tiles).
- On a large map Palladium ore spawns below a depth of 1,270 feet (635 tiles).

You can also fish for it in hardmode.